# Module not found: Error: Package path ./compat is not exported from package

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm working on my project and all of a sudden, I got the following message from the compiler and don't know how to solve the problem:

> ```
> ERROR in ./src/frontend/service/AuthService.ts 8:0-39
>
> Module not found: Error: Package path ./compat is not exported from package /Users/chuben/Desktop/Coding_Projects/ecommerce-react-node/final.frontend.project/node_modules/firebase (see exports field in /Users/chuben/Desktop/Coding_Projects/ecommerce-react-node/final.frontend.project/node_modules/firebase/package.json)
>
> ERROR in ./src/frontend/ui/page/RegisterPage/index.tsx 14:0-39
>
> Module not found: Error: Package path ./compat is not exported from package /Users/chuben/Desktop/Coding_Projects/ecommerce-react-node/final.frontend.project/node_modules/firebase (see exports field in /Users/chuben/Desktop/Coding_Projects/ecommerce-react-node/final.frontend.project/node_modules/firebase/package.json)
> ```

I don't understand what the problem is and how should I export the path correctly? I will really appreciate anyone who can help solve this problem. Thanks in advance!

Hopefully, I don't have to do everything from scratch by starting a new project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue there. I shouldn't set the following in my React page, or else the system will try to search the module for the variable or sth.

> const [firebaseUid,setFirebaseUid]=useState<String|undefined>(undefined);

Comment: Yes. After changing it to simply uid, setUid, there's nothing wrong anymore.